# Method reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type

Tags: java, method-reference

```
String[] arr = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"};
Arrays.sort(arr, String::compareToIgnoreCase); //can compile
Arrays.sort(arr, "a"::compareToIgnoreCase); //can't compile
```

1. why the "a"::compareToIgnoreCase cannot compile? if we can said String::compareToIgnoreCase has an implicit String argument (this), why we cannot said "a"::compareToIgnoreCase has an implicit "a" as argument? ("a" compare to "First", "a" compare to "Second".....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"a"::compareToIgnoreCase` is a method reference to a method of a single argument, which compares a given `String` to the `String` "a". The implicit argument is always equal to "a".

A `Comparator`'s `Compare` method requires two given `String` instances.

Maybe if you write the method references as lambda expressions it would be clearer:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)); //can compile

Arrays.sort(arr, (x) -> "a".compareToIgnoreCase(x)); // can't compile, since a method with 
                                                     // two arguments is expected
```

Comment: Yes, think in lambda expression is always clearer than method reference